How do I write an advice to override an org-roam function?
I have an issue with org-roam graph https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/issues/2427 .
How do I write my config so that I do not have to patch the org roam code each time the org-roam gets update or I move my config to another machine?
I do not understand advising functions. I need an example.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

You should move the answer to your question into an actual Answer, and then click the checkmark to accept it.

I needed the :override option in advice-add.
;;; fix graph drawing

(defun org-roam-graph--format-node-fix (node type)
  "Return a graphviz NODE with TYPE.
Handles both Org-roam nodes, and string nodes (e.g. urls)."
  (let (node-id node-properties)
    (if (org-roam-node-p node)
        (let* ((title (org-roam-quote-string (org-roam-node-title node)))
               (shortened-title
                (org-roam-quote-string
                 (pcase org-roam-graph-shorten-titles
                   (`truncate (truncate-string-to-width title org-roam-graph-max-title-length nil nil "..."))
                   (`wrap (org-roam-word-wrap org-roam-graph-max-title-length title))
                   (_ title)))))
          (setq node-id (org-roam-node-id node)
                node-properties `(("label"   . ,shortened-title)
                                  ("URL"     . ,(funcall org-roam-graph-link-builder node))
                                  ("tooltip" . ,(xml-escape-string title)))))
      (setq node-id node
            node-properties (append `(("label" . ,(concat type ":" ;node
                                                          (truncate-string-to-width node 15)
                                                          )))
                                    (when (member type (list "http" "https"))
                                      `(("URL" . ,(xml-escape-string (concat type ":" node))))))))
    (format "\"%s\" [%s];\n"
            node-id
            (mapconcat (lambda (n)
                         (org-roam-graph--dot-option n nil "\""))
                       (append (cdr (assoc type org-roam-graph-node-extra-config))
                               node-properties) ","))))

;;; the advice I need
(advice-add 'org-roam-graph--format-node
            :override
            #'org-roam-graph--format-node-fix)
 

